# "Multiple definitions of node p[1]" Error using WinBUGS

Tags: bayesian, logit, bayes, bugs

I have written the following code in WinBUGS and every time I try to compile the data after loading in the data I get the same error which is "Multiple definitions of node `p[1]`". I have looked online and it appears that every time this error has appeared it is solved in a different way. Would anyone be able to give me a hand in solving this error?

```
model{
    for(i in 1:N) {
    X[i] ~ dbin(p[i],n[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- alpha + beta*X[]
    }
    }

#Data
list(N=9)
X[] n[] p[]
2   1443 1346
3   694 557
4   455 337
5   353 208
6   272 149
7   256 136
8   240 111
9   217 69
10  200 67
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you have sent p in as data and are also defining p through the logit transformation. I'm guessing what you really want is

```
model{
  for(i in 1:N) {
    p[i] ~ dbin(theta[i],n[i])
    logit(theta[i]) <- alpha + beta*X[i]
  }
}
```

As I'm guessing p is the number of successes.

Comment: This makes sense and the code runs, however when I try to generate initial values I get another error which is a "Trap" page. I have used the following code: model{
 for(i in 1:N) {
 p[i] ~ dbin(theta[i],n[i])
 logit(theta[i]) <- alpha + beta*X[i]
 }
 alpha ~ dflat()
 beta ~ dflat()
 }

Comment: It is unhelpful error messages like this that pushed me to use JAGS and now Stan rather than WinBUGS.